# How to print an item with least combined rank in two lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have just started with Python and trying to solve this problem. Given the two lists, I have to print the item with the least combined rank in the two lists. Here is my approach so far, but it seems to be wrong:

```
rest_1 = ['pizza','potato','tomato','burger']
rest_2 = ['onion','tomato','pizza','tea']


for i in range(1,len(rest_1)):
    for j in range(1,len(rest_2)):
        if rest_1[i]==rest_2[j]:
            print(rest_2[i])
```

Here, the answer should be Pizza since it has the least combined rank. But my logic is wrong for sure. Would love any help.

Comment: What is combined rank? Sum of index in each list?

Comment: @BallpointBen yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dict that maps the items of the second list to their respective indices, then iterate through the items of the first list and get the corresponding index of the same item in the second list to calculate the sum of both, and use the `min` function to get the least of them. Use infinity (`float('inf')`) as an index in case an item in the first list is not in the second list so it would not be considered:

```
def least_ranked(first, second):
    mapping = dict(map(reversed, enumerate(second)))
    return min((i + mapping.get(v, float('inf')), v) for i, v in enumerate(first))[1]
```

so that:

```
least_ranked(rest_1, rest_2)
```

returns: `'pizza'`

Comment: it says name 'item' is not defined.

Comment: Oops fixed then.